# Выделение памяти под двумерный символьный массив

Tags: c++, строки, память

Нужно разбить сроку на 20 частей, начиная с определенного символа. Под подстроки нужно динамически выделить память. Сама программа разбивает все как нужно, но после этого выдает ошибку памяти. Наверное, я где-то вышел за границы массива.

```
//Чтение файла
int size; char *fileData;
ifstream file("big.txt", ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

fileData = new char[size + 1];

file.read(fileData, size);
fileData[size] = 0;
file.close();
//cout << fileData << endl;

//Остаток от деления на количество файлов
int ost = size % 20;
cout << ost << endl;

//Целая часть
int col = (size - ost) / 20;
cout << col << endl;

char **Pack = new char*[20]; //Выделяем память под количество строк
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) Pack[i] = new char[size];

for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    strcpy(Pack[i] - col*i, fileData);
    cout << Pack[i] << endl << endl << endl;
    //printf("string - %s",pack[0]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
    delete[]Pack[i]; 
}
delete[]Pack;
```

> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer
>
> CRT обнаружил, что приложение пишет в память после завершения буфера памяти

Ошибка именно в очистке памяти (последние 4 строки), т.к. без них работает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то вот тут

```
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
    strcpy(Pack[i] - col*i, fileData);
```

при `i==0` вы копируете **всю** строку из `fileData`, включая нулевой символ - итого `size+1` байт, а выделяете всего `size` байт... И в итоге, вероятно, перезаписываете служебную структуру диспетчера памяти.

При `i` побольше вы вообще пишете в память **до** выделенной. Т.е. чистая запись в запрещенное место, за пределы массива...

**Update**

Вот примерный вариант, если я верно понял, что вам нужно:

```
char longStr[] = "vbjhghjacvskv sdghjv sdghsdcv "
    "sdfhvghvdfghvsfdhgvksuygrugfqgawg q4ut6r7843"
    " grygfuyqwg gxegfuyegwdg fxkugsygwkxgywgryxg"
    "jakysgqgxcfasgsdfhjkahshchhcgashgsdfggsksgjs";

int main()
{
    const int partCount = 20;
    const int strLength = strlen(longStr);
    int partSize = (strLength+partCount-1) / partCount;

    char **Pack = new char*[partCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < partCount; ++i)
    {
        Pack[i] = new char[partSize+1];
        strncpy(Pack[i],longStr+partSize*i,partSize);
        Pack[i][partSize] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < partCount; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Part " << setw(2) << i << ": " << Pack[i] << endl;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < partCount; ++i)
    {
        delete[] Pack[i];
    }
    delete[] Pack;

}
```

Только учтите, что, например, если берем, скажем, строку из 63 букв и бьем на 20 частей - то если бить по 3 символа - то получается 3 символа лишних, если по 4 - то будет 16 строк, и 4 пустые строки.

Так что вам нужно как-то точнее описать (а потом реализовать :)) свой принцип разбиения строки на части.

Comment: Все-ровно ошибка

Comment: Мда, я недостотрел, что вы из `Pack[i]` еще и вычитание делаете :( И куда ж вы пишете? в место **до** выделенной памяти?

Comment: Что-то я не совсем понимаю, strcpy работает так, что после - мы пишем значение, с которого нужно копировать, и у меня первый цикл такой strcpy(Pack[0] - 0, fileData); то есть в Pack[0] записывается весь fileData, собственно как мне и нужно, а перед этим циклом я выделяю память, так в чем конкретно ошибка?

Comment: `strcpy(Pack[i] - col*i, fileData);` - Чему у вас равно `Pack[i] - col*i` при `i>0`, Куда указывает этот указатель?

Comment: какой указатель? при col = 4 (для примера) первая итерация strcpy(Pack[0] - 0, fileData); вторая - strcpy(Pack[1] - 4, fileData); третья strcpy(Pack[2] - 8, fileData); четвертая - strcpy(Pack[3] - 12, fileData); и так далее, после минуса стоит значение - это номер символа с которого копируется в Pack[i], все копируется и выводит нормально, а при освобождении памяти - ошибка, в третьей с конца строке

Comment: *"после минуса стоит значение - это номер символа с которого копируется в Pack[i]"* - Итак, имеем - для конкретности - пусть `size=20`, `Pack[2] = 1000`, т.е. вы выделили память в 20 байт, и она начинается с некоей 1000-й ячейки. Т.е. вы можете писать в ячейки 1000, 1001, ..., 1019. Вы делаете, скажем, `strcpy(Pack[2]-5,fileData)` - т.е. пишете данные, начиная с ячейки `Pack[2]-5`, т.е. в ячейки 995, 996,... Теперь понятно? То, что "пишется нормально" - это не критерий. Например, вы вместо одной переменной пишете результат в другую - пишется-то нормально, но результат-то неверный :)

Comment: ну а как это исправить, конкретно для моего примера?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.